# Cypress: using this vs @ for fixtures?

Tags: cypress

So on Cypress's documents it mentions (here: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases#Sharing-Context):

> Keep in mind that there are use cases for both approaches because they
> have different ergonomics.
>
> When using this.users we have access to it synchronously, whereas when
> using cy.get('@users') it becomes an asynchronous command.
>
> You can think of the cy.get('@users') as doing the same thing as
> cy.wrap(this.users).

This is in regards to using `this.fixture` vs using `cy.get('@fixture')` for example (I realize there are other use cases but lets just stick with fixtures for now)

I realize it explains sync vs async above....but when would you WANT to use a synchonous `this` to access a fixture vs not? Maybe within a `then` function/callback? (If you needed to access a fixture within a response to a request or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing it does is reduce callback nesting when multiple aliases are required in one expression, for example

```js
cy.wrap('1').as('a')
// more actions
cy.wrap('2').as('b')
// more actions
cy.wrap('3').as('c')

// assert all values
cy.get('@a').then(a => {
  cy.get('@b').then(b => {
    cy.get('@c').then(c => {
      expect(a+b+c).to.eq(d)
    })
  })
})
```

compare to

```js
cy.wrap('1').as('a')
// more actions
cy.wrap('2').as('b')
// more actions
cy.wrap('3').as('c')

// assert all values
cy.then(function() {
  expect(this.a + this.b + this.c).to.eq(d)
})
```